# Convert scn to glb

Tags: ios, graphics, 3d, converters, assimp

I am trying to covert an scn file to GLB format. I used `assimp` and get the following error. It is in the [supported import format](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/doc/Fileformats.md)

```
param = test.glb
assimp export: select file format: 'glb2' (GL Transmission Format v. 2 (binary))
Launching asset import ...           OK
Validating postprocessing flags ...  OK
ERROR: Failed to load file: COB: Could not found magic id: `Caligari`
```

Anyway to get past this? Or would any other CLI or API help in the conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please open an Issue-Report on [Asset-Importer-Lib](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) with a small issue, which can be used to reproduce the issue? The COB-Format is not so stable in the Assimp and it would be great to make this more stable.

I think this issue is caused by a not correctly parsed magic-token at the beginning, which needs to get fixes.

Comment: I opened an Issue